# How can I find out which row of data from this excel sheet is duplicated the most

Tags: python-3.x, excel

I am trying to find out which row (street name) has the most crimes in an excel spreadsheet. I have found the sum for the highest amount of crimes I just can't find the actual row that generated that many occurrences.

import os
import csv

def main():
#create and save the path to the file...
fileToRead = "C:/Users/zacoli4407/Documents/Intro_To_Scipting/Crime_Data_Set.csv"

```
highestNumberOfCrimes = 0
data = []
rowNumber = 0
count = 0

with open(fileToRead, 'r') as dataToRead:
    dataToRead = open(fileToRead, 'r') # open the access to the file
    reader = csv.reader(dataToRead) # gives the ability to read from the file

    for row in reader:
        if row[4].isnumeric():
            if int(row[4]) > highestNumberOfCrimes:
                highestNumberOfCrimes = int(row[4])
                rowNumber = count
            data.append([row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]]) #row 3 has the street name I am trying to acquire
            count += 1
            
print(highestNumberOfCrimes)
with open("crime.txt", "w") as outputFile:
    outputFile.write("The highest number of crimes is: \n")
    outputFile.write(str(highestNumberOfCrimes))
```

main()

Comment: does row[4] always have integers? or it can also have non-numeric values?

Comment: I did `.isnmumeric()` on row[4] to skip the title of the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(float)
with open(fileToRead, 'r') as dataToRead:
    reader = csv.reader(dataToRead)
    header = next(reader)
    for  row in reader:
        result[row[3]]  += float(row[4])

#Now to get the street with maximum number of crimes
mx = max(result, key = result.get)
print(mx)

#to get the maximum number of crimes
print(result[mx])
```